# object_recognition_core failed to run corre

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
Im fairly new here and I've been trying ROS for fun for a few days and finally got stuck at object_recognition_core.

```
I finished the installation of fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 and then object_recognition from the ROS repositories:
```

`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-object-recognition-core`

```
Then I followed the quick guide of this page:
(ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/ros_quickguide.html)
unfortunately,I failed to run this in the third Terminal:
```

`rosrun object_recognition_core orb_template.py -o my_textured_plane`

```
 it says:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named orb_template.py below /opt/ros/fuerte/share/object_recognition_core
 
 Anyone knows how to solve this?
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49516/object_recognition_core-failed-to-run-corre/) by [ThomasWayne](https://answers.ros.org/users/3697/thomaswayne/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

orb_template.py is now found in the object_recognition_capture package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try to rosmake this package ,,

```
rosmake object_recognition_core
```

if No failure happened in rosmake ,try again

```
rosrun object_recognition_core orb_template.py -o my_textured_plane
```

---

Originally posted by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) with karma: 464 on 2012-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1